# Maven PMD Plugin to compile XSLT files

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, pmd

Is it possible to use Maven PMD plugin to validate XSLT files and generate reports? If so can you please provide a sample usage of plugin configuration.

Comment: PMD analyzis source code not XSLT files. I would suggest to take a look at  http://mojo.codehaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/

Comment: @khmarbaise - PMD has XML and XSL module (http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.3.1/pmd-xml/index.html), so Jai's question is valid for me

Comment: Ah...i wasn't aware of thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the quick turnaround… Could you please post a sample plugin configuration for validating XSL files?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an elegant solution, but I got it working with the following settings: You'll need to add the folder where your xsl files are as a source folder and make sure, the pmd plugin scans *.xsl files and has the pmd-xml dependency.

I'll assume, the xsl files are located in `src/main/xsl` and use a file extension of `xsl`.

I'll take version 5.2.3 of PMD, as this is what the maven-pmd-plugin is built on. I enabled the only built-in ruleset `rulesets/xsl/xpath.xml`. The rules are described in the [pmd documentation](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.3.1/pmd-xml/rules/xsl/xpath.html).

Here's the complete `pom.xml` file:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd.it</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-example-xsl</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
               <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>1.9.1</version>
               <configuration>
                   <sources>
                       <source>src/main/xsl</source>
                   </sources>
               </configuration>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <goals><goal>add-source</goal></goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <rulesets>
                        <ruleset>rulesets/xsl/xpath.xml</ruleset>
                    </rulesets>
                    <printFailingErrors>true</printFailingErrors>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.xsl</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals><goal>check</goal></goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                   <dependency>
                       <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
                       <artifactId>pmd-xml</artifactId>
                       <version>5.2.3</version>
                   </dependency>
               </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here's a sample xsl file, that triggers the "UseConcatOnce" rule. Store this under `src/main/xsl/sample.xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('double', concat('concat'))"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you run now `mvn clean verify`, you should see a failing build:

```
...
[INFO] --- maven-pmd-plugin:3.4:check (default) @ maven-example-xsl ---
[INFO] PMD Failure: sample.xsl:4 Rule:UseConcatOnce Priority:3 The xpath concat() function accepts as many arguments as required, you may be able to factorize this expression.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```